# How does the Geocoder class in android work?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, geocoding

I wanted to peek in the Geocoder class in android to understand how it works. But when I opened it in the ide I found this class had nothing much but only few methods which only created some RuntimeException objects. So how does it work. What pattern is it using ?

this the class which I got when the .class file was Decompiled by the ide.

```
public final class Geocoder {
        public Geocoder(Context context, Locale locale) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }

        public Geocoder(Context context) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }

        public static boolean isPresent() {
         throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }

public List<Address> getFromLocation(double latitude, double longitude, 
  int maxResults) throws IOException {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public List<Address> getFromLocationName(String locationName, int maxResults) throws IOException {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public List<Address> getFromLocationName(String locationName, int maxResults, double lowerLeftLatitude, double lowerLeftLongitude, double upperRightLatitude, double upperRightLongitude) throws IOException {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's actually implemented by a qualifying service (probably Google Play Services in most cases) and this is not open source. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/Geocoder.java

Comment: "The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework."

Comment: @KenWolf so this qualifying service is the backend  service which is required by the Geocoder as mentioned in the [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) reference  ?

Comment: yes, that's my understanding

Comment: I am looking for the design perspective of this class. wanted to understand how is it designed .

Comment: Is it like If the qualifying service class/backend class(or may be bytecode) is available on the device it will use that and if its not available it will use the one with no implemention(one with only Exception instantiation)?